# How to work with AWS elasticache for redis from local spring boot application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, redis, amazon-elasticache

How to work with AWS elastic cache for Redis from local spring boot application?

I am getting connection timed out: Primary End Point of the elastic cache for Redis /IP Address:6379

Over the internet, I did not find any article or video showing the proper way to do the same.

Comment: How do you know that your EC instance is reachable at all from where your application is running? It makes sense to test the connectivity using a tool like `nc` first and double check all the security groups, routing tables and network ACLs.

Comment: Try this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html . Also in EC2 Instance you can install python and using python redis library do a quick test on connectivity